# ILSpy on .net Compact Framework

Tags: compact-framework, ilspy

In ILSpy version 2.3.1.1855, I'm trying to decompile System.dll (to troubleshoot a problem with HttpWebRequest). This dll is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE`. I get a list of types and members, but no code. Instead, this exception shows in the ILSpy code window:

> ICSharpCode.Decompiler.DecompilerException: Error decompiling System.Net.WebResponse System.Net.WebRequest::GetResponse()
>    ---> System.OverflowException: Array dimensions exceeded supported range.
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.StackSlot.ModifyStack(StackSlot[] stack, Int32 popCount, Int32 pushCount, ByteCode pushDefinition)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.StackAnalysis(MethodDefinition methodDef)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.ILAst.ILAstBuilder.Build(MethodDefinition methodDef, Boolean optimize, DecompilerContext context)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody(MethodDefinition methodDef, DecompilerContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.CreateMethodBody(MethodDefinition methodDef, DecompilerContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.CreateMethod(MethodDefinition methodDef)
>      at ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder.AddMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>      at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.CSharpLanguage.DecompileMethod(MethodDefinition method, ITextOutput output, DecompilationOptions options)
>      at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.DecompileNodes(DecompilationContext context, ITextOutput textOutput)
>      at ICSharpCode.ILSpy.TextView.DecompilerTextView.<>c__DisplayClass16.b__15()

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are just stubs.  You need to decompile the actual BCL libraries, for example:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\Debugger\BCL\System.dll`